# How to start Android native dialer app at the favorites / call history / contacts screen

Tags: android, android-dialer

I want my Android app to open the native dialer, so that the user can choose a contact to call.

I know how to open the native dialer app from my application.  Something like this opens it at the KEYPAD screen.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

But I want to open it at the screen which has the favorites / call history / contacts tabs and the search box (I'm not sure what this screen is called).

Is there an intent that would open the native dialer here, instead of opening it at the keypad screen.  The user can press back from the keypad screen to get to where I want them, but that is an extra step I don't want them to have to do.

Thanks
NickB

Comment: There is an intent for contacts. Won't that solve your issue ?

Comment: I agree I could fire an intent that starts the native Contacts app, and optionally specify a contact to display, then the user can call them from there.  But that isn't quite what I want.  I specifically want to open the native dialer app at the favorites / call history / contacts screen, ideally on the favorites tab.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think it's going to work the way you want it. Even if you get success to get it work for some phones, it would be challenging to make it work for all because every OEM has their own dialer app. Also, you can take a look at dialer app code in AOSP. You may get a clue from there.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a way to do what I want.  I understand this probably won't  work on all devices:    i.putExtra("add_call_mode", true);